# Android navigation app that can download entire US region offline

Tags: android, offline, navigation

I use an Android phone but do not have a data contract.

What app options do I have that allow me to navigate without a mobile data connection?

I would like the entire content of the United States to be downloaded, at the minimum.  I would like to be able to use this navigation by car.

It must be turn by turn navigation that recalculates.

I would prefer not to pay to much.

Comment: There are plenty of [navigation apps on Android](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_navigation) fitting that description (no, Google Maps won't really fit). So what do you want to achive once the map content has been downloaded? Would you be willing to pay for a good one, and if so, how much at maximum? As it currently stands, your question is a bit thin (or too broad). Please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) to fill the gaps.

Comment: @Izzy I removed the iPhone part.  Just Android, I would like it to cover the entire United States without downloading additional content.  I'm not sure how to make it much narrower or less broad.

Comment: OK, navigate then. Car? Bike? On foot? Many specific apps available :)

Comment: @Izzy Car.  It must be turn by turn navigation that recalculates.

Comment: Recalculation without network connection will be hard. But see my answer below: Maybe you can live with having the recalculation made on mobile data, as long as all else is already available offline :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of apps which would match your description. Some of them come for free, some require a little fee:

#### OsmAnd

Available in a [free version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand) and a [paid version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand.plus) (~EUR 3.50) at playstore, and the latter one also [for free at F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=net.osmand.plus), this is one of the best known high-quality solutions for Android. Map material can be downloaded per-country for free and then be used offline to navigate. Plenty of plugins, e.g. for parking.

[image: OsmAnd] [image: OsmAnd] [image: OsmAnd]

*OsmAnd* offers offline navigation (incl. voice guidance), special modes for hiking, public transports, skiing, nautical, … and includes a lot of other sources. Material is based on OpenStreetMap, a community project.

#### Locus Map

A bit more costly, *Locus* has a [free version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=menion.android.locus) and a [paid version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=menion.android.locus.pro) (currently ~EUR 8.50) at Google Play. I'm using the latter for years and am quite happy with it: Many different map sources (including those from OpenStreetMap), a lot of useful addons, even supports the Pebble so you get navigation on your wrist. Maps cannot only be downloaded by country, you even can define your wanted area free-hand – e.g. a 10km stripe along the road you want to take. Turn-by-turn navigation, tracking, geo-caching and much more is supported here.

[image: Locus] [image: Locus]

Both are good choices. And there are many more to chose from [in my app list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_navigation).

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps allows you to download an area for offline turn by turn navigation. See here the details https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6291838

[Sygic GPS Navigation & Maps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sygic.aura&referrer=utm_source%3DAndroidPIT%26utm_medium%3DAndroidPIT%26utm_campaign%3DAndroidPIT) is also a good one for Android. As well as [TomTom GPS Navigation Traffic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tomtom.gplay.navapp&referrer=utm_source%3DAndroidPIT%26utm_medium%3DAndroidPIT%26utm_campaign%3DAndroidPIT)

For iPhone, you can also have [Sygic GPS Navigation & Maps](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sygic-gps-navigation-maps/id585193266?mt=8), and [HERE WeGo](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/here-wego-city-navigation/id955837609?mt=8)

Comment: Which ones download the entire US's content?

Comment: @LiamWilliam, I am not sure, but I think that all the other ones except Google Maps. (but still Google Maps is probably better than them.)